# How can I correct the WSDL when the policy expression's "normalized form was too large"

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

So - I've been tasked with creating a proxy client to the following service, but I'm having a heck of a time generating a client that's happy with the requirements. The WSDL is located here: https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1441/EDTService/EDTService?wsdl

When I run svcutil, I get the following output:

```
C:\Temp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\svcutil.exe" /t:code https://ws.conf.
ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1441/EDTService/EDTService?wsdl /out:ebs.cs /config:ebs.con
fig
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.32559]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1441/
EDTService/EDTService?wsdl' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.
Warning: The policy expression was not fully imported because its normalized for
m was too large.
XPath:"XPath Unavailable"

Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://edt.health.on
tario.ca/']/wsdl:binding[@name='EDTPortBinding']

Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is depend
ent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://edt.health.on
tario.ca/']/wsdl:binding[@name='EDTPortBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://edt.health.on
tario.ca/']/wsdl:service[@name='EDTService']/wsdl:port[@name='EDTPort']

Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is depend
ent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://edt.health.on
tario.ca/']/wsdl:binding[@name='EDTPortBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://edt.health.on
tario.ca/']/wsdl:service[@name='EDTService']/wsdl:port[@name='EDTPort.2']
```

I've tried the same command using versions: 3.0.4506.2152, 4.0.30319.18020 and 4.0.30319.32559 with the same outcome. Any ideas?

I have created a proxy using WSDL.exe (inheriting from Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol) at some point but I've had to config everything myself and I'm running into exceptions every time I receive a response (catch the exception, decrypt the response body manually and repeat). Also, I have to use MTOM which makes this custom code work even less.

Comment: I am able to create a Service reference using that link you provided it comes as `EDTService` perhaps you are consuming the web service incorrectly. also is this a public webservice or do you need to have `credentials` when trying to Invoke Web Method calls / usage..?

Comment: I too was also able to create a Service Reference using VS2010. Try just creating from visual studio rather than directly using svcutil (as a test) if VS creates one fine for you then it's the way you are callign svcutil otherwise it's something environmental.

Comment: I can create client code, but I also include the /config:ebs.con
fig flag and it doesn't create the necessary config to use the client. It's not a public webservice, it does require credentials.

Comment: can you show the relevant code vs showing such a large error msg perhaps you are doing something wrong..

Comment: @DJKRAZE Even if you create a service reference, those issues persist as warnings. http://imgur.com/xU1DY25